# Nested mixed-model in Python?

Tags: nested, regression, mixed-models, random-effects

Does anyone know how to do a nested random-effects model in Python? Using statsmodels MixedLM, it gives me a singular matrix error.

Answer (score 0):

the issue arises when you have a column with values 0 throughout
So, you can check the variables you're using in mixedlm model and find out which ones are zero. 
Hope it helps!